# The type 'System.Int32' needs to represent an enumeration type

Tags: c#

I am try toggle a column value. I am using Entity framework database connection.

```
public static void yayinDegistir(int id)
{
    using (vt dc = new vt())
    {
        Testler d = dc.testler.FirstOrDefault(t => t.testId.Equals(id));
        if (d != null)
        {
            d.yayinda = !d.yayinda; //bool value to toggle
            dc.SaveChanges(); //error
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Int32' needs to represent an enumeration type.
```

The Testler class

```
public class Testler
{
    [Key]
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public virtual int testId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Test Adı")]
    public virtual string testAdi { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public virtual string aciklama { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [EnumDataType(typeof(int), ErrorMessage = "{0} mutlaka sayı olmalıdır!")]
    public virtual int testSuresi { get; set; }

    public virtual bool cokluSecim { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public virtual string oneriler { get; set; }

    public virtual bool yayinda { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Sorular> sorular { get; set; }
}
```

Stack trace of error

> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Int32' needs to represent an enumeration type.]
>    System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EnumDataTypeAttribute.IsValid(Object
> ```
>
> value) +40216
>          System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext) +115
>          System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext) +29
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationAttributeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property) +100
>
> ```
> [DbUnexpectedValidationException: An unexpected exception was thrown during validation of 'Test Süresi (saniye) (0 süresiz)' when
> ```
>
> invoking
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EnumDataTypeAttribute.IsValid.
>   See the inner exception for details.]
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.ValidationAttributeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property) +170
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.PropertyValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalMemberEntry property) +108
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidator.ValidateProperties(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalPropertyEntry parentProperty, List`1
>   validationErrors) +100
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.TypeValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext, InternalPropertyEntry property) +69
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Validation.EntityValidator.Validate(EntityValidationContext
>   entityValidationContext) +17
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalEntityEntry.GetValidationResult(IDictionary`2
>   items) +193
>          System.Data.Entity.DbContext.ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary`2 items) +40
>          System.Data.Entity.DbContext.GetValidationErrors() +210
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +44
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +33
>          System.Data.Entity.DbContext.SaveChanges() +20
>          Ramazan.TestIslem.yayinDegistir(Int32 id) in D:\Projects\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\hayatdestek\hayatdestek\Ramazan\Testler.cs:102
>          hayatdestek.Controllers.YonetimController.YayinDegistir(Int32 id) in D:\Projects\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\hayatdestek\hayatdestek\Controllers\YonetimController.cs:180
>          lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +97
>          System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +182
>          System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
>   parameters) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
>   +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.b__7(IAsyncResult
>   *) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
>   +58
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
>   +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass2a.b_*20()
>   +24
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass25.b_*22(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +99
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +14
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c*_DisplayClass4.b_*3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +25
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult
>   ar) +23
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
>          System.Web.Mvc.<>c*_DisplayClasse.b_*d() +31
>          System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.b*_0(Action f) +7
>          System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +23
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +59
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9629296
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

The solution answer from @Pawel

> this exception seems to originate from [EnumDataType(typeof(int),
>   ErrorMessage = "{0} mutlaka sayı olmalıdır!")] where the type should
>   an Enum type and not the simple type. Try removing this attribute to
>   test things work. Note the EnumDataType attribute is not used by EF
>   and this is issue is probably not related to EF.

Comment: Shouldn't `d.yayinda` need to be a `bool` in order to negate its value?

Comment: Your code makes very little sense without context

Comment: on debug seems d.yayinda's value false and !d.yayinda's value is true

Comment: on which line is the debugger throwing up?

Comment: What line is this failing on? What is `d`? What is `d.yayinda`, a Boolean, an Int32, an Enumeration type? I know you say d.yayinda is a Boolean type, but obviously EF thinks something should be an Int32 or enumeration value.

Comment: @Sayse, Add, Edit, Delete, Select all working with same context

Comment: d is variable, d.yayinda is boolean, I am adding the Testler class now sorry

Comment: I'm sure it is all working except you've stated your line with the method call has an error but we know bugger all about what the method is, The stack trace like the error says would be more useful to you also

Comment: dc.SaveChanges() is error line

Comment: this exception seems to originate from `[EnumDataType(typeof(int), ErrorMessage = "{0} mutlaka sayı olmalıdır!")]` where the type should an Enum type and not the simple type. Try removing this attribute to test things work. Note the `EnumDataType` attribute is not used by EF and this is issue is probably not related to EF.

Comment: @Pawel, right. It is fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stack trace:

> [InvalidOperationException: The type 'System.Int32' needs to represent
>   an enumeration type.]
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EnumDataTypeAttribute.IsValid(Object

suggests that this annotation:

```
[EnumDataType(typeof(int), ErrorMessage = "{0} mutlaka sayı olmalıdır!")]
```

on `public virtual int testSuresi { get; set; }` is throwing up.